# Is this INSERT INTO SSMS query safe from SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, sanitization

I'm working on a query using ssms and I am wondering if there are any vulnerabilities that I have left open. The flngKey field forces input to be an int and the fstrWho field has a character limit of 100. The system uses a filter to escape all single quotes by doubling it. The server is run on unicode not varchar (to hopefully protect against unicode smuggling). I'm also using VB.net strict mode on with bind parameters. Any ideas on any vulnerabilities I have left open?

[VB.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHk01.png)
[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkNec.png)

Comment: You are inserting literals via SSMS... instead of it being called by an application, thus there is no injection vector unless you deliberately did it. Or maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: Potentially belaboring the obvious -- why not just use parameters instead of running past a large checklist of how to make textual SQL safe? Then things like "escaping all single quotes" become superfluous as well (and, in fact, actively harmful). The query as shown has no vulnerabilities, of course, but if it's the result of manipulating text, that doesn't say much.

Comment: Unless you show us how **user-provided** content is manipulated we cannot really discuss safety.

Comment: Sql injection is possible without using parameterized query.

Comment: We need to see the VB.net code, not the SQL that you generated from it.

Comment: Queries run from an SSMS query window are not parameterized. Assuming your intent is to avoid SQL injection, use [parameterized queries](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice) in your application.

Comment: added more info sorry

Answer (score 2):

SQL Injection becomes a concern when user inputs are concatenated with dynamic sql.

It usually looks something like this...

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = N'INSERT INTO table (flngKey, fstrWho) VALUES (' + @string_param_1 + N', N'''+ @string_param_2 + N''');'
```

As designed the user inputs values for @string_param_1 & @string_param_2...

```
DECLARE 
    @string_param_1 nvarchar(10) = N'12345',
    @string_param_2 nvarchar(1000) = N'some value';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = N'INSERT INTO table (flngKey, fstrWho) VALUES (' + @string_param_1 + N', N'''+ @string_param_2 + N''');'

EXEC (@sql);
```

and, as designed, the following command is created and executed...

```
INSERT INTO table (flngKey, fstrWho) VALUES (12345, N'some value');
```

The sql injection vulnerability comes from the fact that it directly concatinates the parameter values into the command. So when the bad user comes a long and enters a set of values like this...

```
DECLARE 
    @string_param_1 nvarchar(10) = N'12345',
    @string_param_2 nvarchar(1000) = N'some value''); select * from dbo.customer_billing_info; --';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = N'INSERT INTO table (flngKey, fstrWho) VALUES (' + @string_param_1 + N', N'''+ @string_param_2 + N''');'
--EXEC (@sql);
PRINT(@sql);
```

Now the command being generated looks like this...

```
INSERT INTO table (flngKey, fstrWho) VALUES (12345, N'some value'); select * from dbo.customer_billing_info; --');
```